# hasManyThrough Relationship for Eloquent laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

After a lot of searching  i couldn't find a real solution to my "problem", so if there any one how can help me, i’am all listening

…

I have tree models, Post, User and Profile

```
Post belongsTo user – user hasMany posts == One –to-Many relation
Profile belongsTo user – user hasOne profile == One-to-One relation
```

Database structure

```
User

---- id : primary key
---- email : string
---- name : string
```

…

```
Profile

---- id : primary key
---- user_id : foreign key
---- biography : text
---- facebook : strings
```

…

```
Post

---- id : primary key
---- user_id : foreign key
---- title : string
---- slug : string
---- body : text
```

…

User model

```
class User extends Eloquent  {
    public function posts(){
        return $this->hasMany('Post');
    }
    public function profile(){
        return $this->hasOne('Profile');
    }
}
```

Profile model

```
class Profile extends \Eloquent {
    public function user(){
        return $this->hasOne('User');
    }
}
```

Post model

```
class Post extends \Eloquent {  
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}
```

**HOW** can i get the users biography (or any other properties)  on profiles table through the posts

I hope i was clear enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no `hasManyThrough` in your setup.

First fix this relationship:

```
//Profile    
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}
```

Then simply:

```
$post->user->profile->biography;

$user->profile->biography;
```

There is no *profiles data through the posts*, since both `post` and `profile` belong to the user.

---

There's also another way to link `posts` and `profiles` tables:

```
// Post model
public function profile()
{
  return $this->hasOne('Profile', 'user_id', 'user_id');
}

// Profile model
public function posts()
{
  return $this->hasMany('Post', 'user_id', 'user_id');
}
```

Then:

```
$post->profile->biography;

$profile->posts; // collection of Post models
```

This way you save one query by not fetching the `User` model.